# `map` based on condition

Tags: ruby, struct

I have a struct like this:

```
Struct.new("Test", :loc, :type, :hostname, :ip)

clients = [
Struct::TestClient.new(1, :pc, "pc1", "192.168.0.1")
Struct::TestClient.new(1, :pc, "pc2", "192.168.0.2")
Struct::TestClient.new(1, :tablet, "tablet1", "192.168.0.3")
Struct::TestClient.new(1, :tablet, "tablet2", "192.168.0.3")
and etc...
]
```

If I want to get the IP address of all devices, I can use `test_clients.map(&:ip)`. How do I select the IP addresses of specific devices, say all device types called `"tablet"`? How can I do that with `map`?

Comment: Ruby 2.7 is introducing filter_map for this exact purpose. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444118/map-based-on-condition/56565469#answer-56565469).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do a [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) first

```
clients.select{|c| c.type == 'tablet'}.map(&:ip)
```

Answer (score 21):

**Ruby 2.7+**

Ruby 2.7 is introducing `filter_map` for this exact purpose. It's idiomatic and performant, and I'd expect it to become the norm very soon.

For example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 13]
enum.filter_map { |i| i * 2 if i.even? }
# => [4, 16, 20]
```

Here's a [good read on the subject](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/05/25/ruby-2-7-enumerable-filter-map.html).

Hope that's useful to someone!

Comment: This is the correct answer for 2.7 and above

Answer (score 15):

Answer is as simple as that:

```
clients.map { |client| client.ip if client.type == 'tablet' }.compact
```

Mapping with condition will give nils for clients which failed the condition, for that only we kept `compact`, which will actually flush the nil values.

Comment: No need of using, `select` and `map` as mentioned in the Sergio Tulentsev's answer, as it will result in two loops and comparatively slower.

Comment: `compact` also iterates over the array and checks each value for `nil`. Sergio's answer could actually be faster. In your example, both iterations are over the full length of `clients`, whereas in Sergio's example, the second iteration may be over a smaller set.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate to Sergio Tulentsev's method using `#collect`. I think using `#collect` is semantically correct here. I know the O.P. asked how to use `#map`, but it's my two cents.

```
clients.collect { |c| c.ip if c.type == "tablet" } # will return nils for clients where the type is not "tablet"

# or

clients.select { |c| c.type == "tablet" }.collect(&ip)
```

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate answers, hit the backspace key one too many times and went back to a create rather than edit.

Comment: I'm curious, how do you differentiate a difference between `collect` and `map`? Also, does `collect(&ip)` return what you expect?

Comment: I usually use `collect` when I'm just grabbing values from a set of objects, and `map` when I'm doing a bunch of logic in the block, or returning an array that has changed values. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: The `select`-less version will leave you with `nil`s.

Comment: Oh, true. I didn't think about that too much.

Comment: `collect` is an alias to `map`; It doesn't matter which you use because they're identical. Any difference is most likely due to languages you've used in the past because of familiarity with one or the other. And, as a result, I use `map` because it's easier to type.